# Router only works one level deep and not on root

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I'm trying to upgrade my code to use the router from emberjs master instead of relying on ember-routemanager. My code is mostly based on https://gist.github.com/2728699 . I created a fiddle to show what I am talking about at http://fiddle.jshell.net/pszvJ/19/show/#/posts

When I click on "Test Comments Route" and Test Comment Show". I never get the console.log that I am supposed to have but it works for both "posts" actions.

Also when I try to reach directly /. I get a "Could not find state for path /" even though / should be my root element where I am printing Main Entry Point. In facts, Main Entry Point is logged but it fails afterward.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

According to your fiddle, your router has states:

- root.posts.index (#/posts)
- root.posts.show (#/posts/42)
- root.posts.comments.index (#/posts/comments)
- root.posts.comments.show (#/posts/comments/42)

If you want to handle urls like #/posts/42/comments/1, the "comments" state must be nested into  the "posts.show" state.

And you can't reach "/" directly because you didn't define any state for that url.

See [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DHN2u/2/).

Comment: Thank you! It works. However, I decided to put posts in the root.index so that the connectOutlets from root.index is executed at all times. Since I made this change, I get the error Could not find state for path. The problem is visible here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/DHN2u/5/

I have tried adding a breakpoint in routePath function but it seems to return a state.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. The purpose of ConnectOutlet is to create a view and connect it to a controller and to a handlebars {{outlet}}. Why do you want to do this "at all times"? You may find useful information [here](https://emberjs-staging-new.herokuapp.com/guides/outlets#toc_the-router).

Comment: I want to have a structure where I must absolutely have the previous result. In root, I want to initialize the view. In post index, I want to show the available posts. In post show, I want to show a single post but I also want the post list to appear. Imagine that you have a left sidepanel with the list of post and when we select a post, we have the details on right.  That's why I want my post.show to depend on post.index so that I can always have the post list even when reaching directly for a post. By the way, thanks for the link. It's the best example I've seen so far.